# MPI error in communicating with many to many processors

Tags: c++, mpi, openmpi

I am writing a code, where each processor must interact with multiple processors.

Ex: I have 12 processors, so Processor 0 has to communicate to say 1,2,10 and 9. Lets call them as neighbours of Processor 0. Similarly I have
Processor 1 has to communicate to say 5 ,3.
Processor 2 has to communicate to 5,1,0,10,11
and so on. 
The flow of data is 2 ways, i.e Processor 0 must send data to 1,2,10 and 9 and also receive data from them.
Also, there is no problem in Tag calculation.
I have created a code which works like this:

```
for(all neighbours) 
{
store data in vector<double> x;

     MPI_Send(x)
}
MPI_BARRIER();
for(all neighbours)
{
MPI_Recv(x);
do work with x
}
```

Now I testing this algorithm for different size of x and different arrangement of neighbours. The code works for some, but doesnot work for others, it simply resorts to deadlock.
I have also tried:

```
for(all neighbours) 
{
store data in vector<double> x;

     MPI_ISend(x)
}
MPI_Test();
for(all neighbours)
{
MPI_Recv(x);
do work with x
}
```

The result is same, although the deadlock is replcaed by NaN in result, as MPI_Test() tells me that some of the MPI_Isend() operation are not complete and it jumps immediately to MPI_Recv().

Can anyone guide me in this matter, what am I dong wrong? Or is my fundamental approach itself is incorrect?

EDIT: I am attaching code snippet for better understanding of the problem. I am basically workin on parallelizing an unstructured 3D-CFD solver

I have attached one of the files, with some explanation. I am not broadcasting, I am looping over the neighbours of the parent processor to send the data across the interface( this can be defined as a boundary between two interfaces) .

So, If say  I have 12 processors, and say Processor 0 has to communicate to say 1,2,10 and 9. So 0 is the parent processor and 1,2,10 and 9 are its neighbours.

As the file was too long and a part of the solver, to make things simple, I have only kept the MPI function in it.

```
void Reader::MPI_InitializeInterface_Values() {
double nbr_interface_id;
Interface *interface;
MPI_Status status;
MPI_Request send_request, recv_request;
int err, flag;
int err2;
char buffer[MPI_MAX_ERROR_STRING];
int len;
int count;


for (int zone_no = 0; zone_no<this->GetNumberOfZones(); zone_no++) { // Number of zone per processor is 1, so basically each zone is an independent processor
    UnstructuredGrid *zone = this->ZoneList[zone_no];
    int no_of_interface = zone->GetNumberOfInterfaces();
    // int count;
    long int count_send = 0;
    long int count_recv = 0;
    long int max_size = 10000; // can be set from test case later
    int max_size2 = 199;

    int proc_no = FlowSolution::processor_number;
    for (int interface_no = 0; interface_no < no_of_interface; interface_no++) { // interface is defined as a boundary between two zones


        interface = zone->GetInterface(interface_no);
        int no_faces = interface->GetNumberOfFaces();
        if (no_faces != 0) {

            std::vector< double > Variable_send; // The vector which stores the data to be sent across the interface
            std::vector< double > Variable_recieve;
            int total_size = FlowSolution::VariableOrder.size() * no_faces;
            Variable_send.resize(total_size);
            Variable_recieve.resize(total_size);
            int nbr_proc_no = zone->GetInterface(interface_no)->GetNeighborZoneId(); // neighbour of parent processor

                int j = 0;
                nbr_interface_id = interface->GetShared_Interface_ID();

                for (std::map<VARIABLE, int>::iterator iterator = FlowSolution::VariableOrder.begin(); iterator != FlowSolution::VariableOrder.end(); iterator++) {

                    for (int face_no = 0; face_no < no_faces; face_no++) {
                        Face *face = interface->GetFace(face_no);
                        int owner_id = face->Getinterface_Original_face_owner_id();
                        double value_send = zone->GetInterface(interface_no)->GetFace(face_no)->GetCell(owner_id)->GetPresentFlowSolution()->GetVariableValue((*iterator).first);
                        Variable_send[j] = value_send;
                        j++;
                    }
                }
                count_send = nbr_proc_no * max_size + nbr_interface_id; // tag for data to be sent
                err2 = MPI_Isend(&Variable_send.front(), total_size, MPI_DOUBLE, nbr_proc_no, count_send, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &send_request);
        }// end of sending

    } // all the processors have sent data to their corresponding neighbours

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    for (int interface_no = 0; interface_no < no_of_interface; interface_no++) { // loop over of neighbours of the current processor to receive data

        interface = zone->GetInterface(interface_no);
        int no_faces = interface->GetNumberOfFaces();
        if (no_faces != 0) {
            std::vector< double > Variable_recieve; // The vector which collects the data sent across the interface from 
            int total_size = FlowSolution::VariableOrder.size() * no_faces;
            Variable_recieve.resize(total_size);
            count_recv = proc_no * max_size + interface_no; // tag to receive data
            int nbr_proc_no = zone->GetInterface(interface_no)->GetNeighborZoneId();
            nbr_interface_id = interface->GetShared_Interface_ID();
                MPI_Irecv(&Variable_recieve.front(), total_size, MPI_DOUBLE, nbr_proc_no, count_recv, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &recv_request);

                /* Now some work is done using received data */
                int j = 0;
                for (std::map<VARIABLE, int>::iterator iterator = FlowSolution::VariableOrder.begin(); iterator != FlowSolution::VariableOrder.end(); iterator++) {
                    for (int face_no = 0; face_no < no_faces; face_no++) {
                        double value_recieve = Variable_recieve[j];
                        j++;
                        Face *face = interface->GetFace(face_no);
                        int owner_id = face->Getinterface_Original_face_owner_id();
                        interface->GetFictitiousCell(face_no)->GetPresentFlowSolution()->SetVariableValue((*iterator).first, value_recieve);
                        double value1 = face->GetCell(owner_id)->GetPresentFlowSolution()->GetVariableValue((*iterator).first);
                        double face_value = 0.5 * (value1 + value_recieve);
                        interface->GetFace(face_no)->GetPresentFlowSolution()->SetVariableValue((*iterator).first, face_value);
                    }
                }
                // Variable_recieve.clear();

        }

    }// end of receiving
```

}

Comment: This can also be called as a case of MPI simultaneous communication between overlapping processes

Comment: The first approach cant work because the MPI_Send is blocking, so none of your processes can get to the Recv call as they will be hung on an MPI_Send, or on the MPI_Barrier if they didnt call MPI_Send. The second approach could work, but can you edit in a snippet of the actual code? You might be doing something wrong with your data buffers but its not clear from the pseudocode.

Comment: Given that the second case uses different buffers with a lifetime that is long enough, you are still missing the MPI_Wait(all). Clearly the MPI_Isend doesn't complete immediately, it will complete the latest when you call MPI_Wait(all) with this request. So the MPI_Test may or may not return a success. I advice you to read the documentation, then you understnad.

Comment: Topologies simplify communication among neighbors. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mpi/9423/process-topologies/29195/graph-topology-creation-and-communication#t=201703131312167569989) example.

Comment: Thanks everyone for replying.  I have posted the code snippet. Please feel free to reply and ask any part that you don't understand. I have tried to put comments in the code to make it easy to understand.

Comment: Please try to make a minimal working example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Also you do not need barriers in this code at all. Use mpi waitall as I outlined.

Comment: BTW, your first code snippet is exactly "Example 5.27" from MPI 3.1 standard.

Comment: Also remove code duplication from your example. And current structure is simply racy. From the point of view of p2p operations you can simply ignore barriers, because MPI_Barier will block until everybody enters a collective, but it does not wait until outstanding non-blocking operations finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using AllGatherV, the problem can be solved. All I did was made the send count such that the send count only had the processors that I wanted to communicate with. Other processors had 0 send count.
This solved my problem

Thank you everyone for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Working from the problem statement:

- Processor 0 has to send to 1, 2, 9 and 10, and receive from them.
- Processor 1 has to send to 5 and 3, and receive from them.
- Processor 2 has to send to 0, 1, 5, 10 and 11, and receive from them.
- There are 12 total processors.

You can make life easier if you just run a 12-step program:

- Step 1: Processor 0 sends, others receive as needed, then the converse occurs.
- Step 2: Processor 1 sends, others receive as needed, then the converse occurs.
- ...
- Step 12: Profit - there's nothing left to do (because every other processor has already interacted with Processor 11).

Each step can be implemented as an MPI_Scatterv (some sendcounts will be zero), followed by an MPI_Gatherv.  22 total calls and you're done.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I think your way will work, if same data has to be transferred between parent and its neighbours.But I have a different problem at hand. You can see the snippet  i edited.

Comment: @samurai_01: Not sure what you mean by "same data."

Answer (score 0):

There may be several possible reasons for a deadlock, so you have to be more specific, e. g. standard says: "When standard send operations are used, then a deadlock situation may occur where both processes are blocked because buffer space is not available."

You should use both Isend and Irecv. The general structure should be:

```
MPI_Request req[n];

MPI_Irecv(..., req[0]);
// ...
MPI_Irecv(..., req[n-1]);
MPI_Isend(..., req[0]);
// ...
MPI_Isend(..., req[n-1]);

MPI_Waitall(n, req, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, If you see the snippet I've attached, I have to transfer data from processor to its neighbors. I haven't tried the MPI_Waitall() but will try this and let you know.